# Embedding google map in static FBML pages

Tags: facebook, google-maps, iframe, embed

I am looking out for a way to embed a google map into a static fbml tab in one of my fan pages. I think few saw FB has scrapped of iframe support for static fbml and stuff. I want to embed the map wthout any user actions involvement.

I am wondering how to do this? Could some one help please?

Answer (score 0):

The [`iframe`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/iframe) doesn't work on **landing** page of a tab, it works in inner pages. For example if your landing tab page is index.php, you need to make on image or link on that page to go to inner.php page and this is where you can use the [`fb:iframe`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/iframe) tag. In your iframe you should be able to put google map.

Comment: Well, I am adding the code in a non-landing page. I don't see the image embedded :( The code is as follows, <fb:iframe src="http://some_url"></fb:iframe>

Comment: here is an example i have used iframes in inner pages for jquery and more stuff: http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=120196931351044&v=app_120196931351044

Comment: Wow thats fantastic :) How did you do it? Also, could you tell me how to add an "facebook application" to an fan page? I am a novice :(